# Setting order of decorations on a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, layers

I'm trying to make paths that are shaded to as to appear as cylinders with spherical ends.

I've found a way to do this with decorations.

I use vertical shading on rectangles for the path segments, and radial shading on circles for the path ends.

I need to get the ends visually behind the segments.  I have thought of two ways to do this.

One method is to draw both ends before I draw the segments.  The downside of this is that I don't have the right angle for the radial shading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\pgfdeclarelayer{barends}
\pgfsetlayers{barends,main}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbar}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=2pt,next state=middle]{
  % sphere on end
  \begin{pgfscope}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}{5pt}
  \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
  % sphere on start
  \begin{pgfscope}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{5pt}
  \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
  % first cylindrical segment
  \begin{pgfscope}
  \pgfpathrectanglecorners
    {\pgfpoint{-1pt}{-5pt}}
    {\pgfpoint{3pt}{5pt}}
  \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
  }
  \state{middle}[width=2pt]
  {
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
      {\pgfpoint{-1pt}{-5pt}}
      {\pgfpoint{3pt}{5pt}}
    \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
    \end{pgfscope}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
  }
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=cylindricalbar]
    \pgfdeclareradialshading[mycolor,white]
      {barendshading}
      {\pgfpoint{0bp}{5bp}}
      {color(0bp)=(white);
       color(28bp)=(mycolor);
       color(60bp)=(mycolor)}

    \pgfdeclareverticalshading[mycolor,white]
      {barshading}
      {100bp}
      {color(0bp)=(mycolor); 
       color(25bp)=(mycolor); 
       color(55bp)=(white); 
       color(75bp)=(mycolor);
       color(100bp)=(mycolor)}


  \colorlet{mycolor}{green}
  \path [decorate]     (0,0) -- (0,3);
  \colorlet{mycolor}{red}
  \path [decorate]     (3,0) .. controls (3,2) and  (2,3) ..  (0,3);
  \colorlet{mycolor}{blue}
  \path [decorate] (0,0) -- (3,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bar with misaligned shading on end]

The second method is to put the bar ends on a layer that is placed behind the main layer.  The downside to this is that if I draw two different bars, the end of the second bar lies behind the body of the first bar so it looks strange.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\pgfdeclarelayer{barends}
\pgfsetlayers{barends,main}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbar}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=2pt,next state=middle]{
  % sphere on start
  \begin{pgfscope}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{5pt}
  \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
  % first cylindrical segment
  \begin{pgfscope}
  \pgfpathrectanglecorners
    {\pgfpoint{-1pt}{-5pt}}
    {\pgfpoint{3pt}{5pt}}
  \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
  }
  \state{middle}[width=2pt]
  {
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
      {\pgfpoint{-1pt}{-5pt}}
      {\pgfpoint{3pt}{5pt}}
    \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
    \end{pgfscope}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
  % sphere on end
  \begin{pgfscope}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{barends}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}{5pt}
  \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfscope}
  }
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=cylindricalbar]
    \pgfdeclareradialshading[mycolor,white]
      {barendshading}
      {\pgfpoint{0bp}{5bp}}
      {color(0bp)=(white);
       color(28bp)=(mycolor);
       color(60bp)=(mycolor)}

    \pgfdeclareverticalshading[mycolor,white]
      {barshading}
      {100bp}
      {color(0bp)=(mycolor); 
       color(25bp)=(mycolor); 
       color(55bp)=(white); 
       color(75bp)=(mycolor);
       color(100bp)=(mycolor)}


  \colorlet{mycolor}{green}
  \path [decorate]     (0,0) -- (0,3);
  \colorlet{mycolor}{red}
  \path [decorate]     (3,0) .. controls (3,1) and  (1,3) ..  (0,3);
  \colorlet{mycolor}{blue}
  \path [decorate] (0,0) -- (3,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bar with squared ends]

Is there any way to 
(1) get the \pgfdecoratedangle of the final segment during while drawing the ininital segment, or
(2) Put the final segment automatically on a layer below the the previous segment, but above all the segments on a previously drawn path?

I realize that I could create a bar end layer for each bar, and properly arrange the layers, but I'd rather not have to add a layer for each bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can defined two decorations (the first to draw the spheres and the second to draw the segments) and use `preaction` and `postaction` to apply them in the right order.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\def\cylindricalsphere{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{5pt}
    \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarspheres}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{\cylindricalsphere}
  \state{middle}[width=1pt]{}
  \state{final}{\cylindricalsphere}
}
\def\cylindricalsgement{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-.55pt}{-5pt}}{\pgfpoint{.55pt}{5pt}}
    \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarsegments}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{\cylindricalsgement}
  \state{middle}[width=1pt]{\cylindricalsgement}
  \state{final}{}
} 

\tikzset{
  cylindricalbar/.style={
    preaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarspheres},
    postaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarsegments},
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclareradialshading[mycolor,white]
  {barendshading}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{5bp}}
  {color(0bp)=(white);color(28bp)=(mycolor);color(60bp)=(mycolor)}

  \pgfdeclareverticalshading[mycolor,white]
  {barshading}{100bp}
  {color(0bp)=(mycolor);color(25bp)=(mycolor); 
    color(55bp)=(white);color(75bp)=(mycolor);color(100bp)=(mycolor)}

  \colorlet{mycolor}{green}
  \path [cylindricalbar]     (0,0) -- (0,3);

  \colorlet{mycolor}{red}
  \path [cylindricalbar]     (4,0) arc(0:90:4);

  \colorlet{mycolor}{red}
  \path [cylindricalbar]     (0,3.5) arc(90:0:3.5);

  \colorlet{mycolor}{blue}
  \path [cylindricalbar] (0,1) -- (2,1);
  \colorlet{mycolor}{blue}
  \path [cylindricalbar] (3,0) -- (0,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect.  You captured the asymmetry I was after, and have the ends working correctly.  I had read about preaction and postaction, but I didn't realize that the whole decoration could be placed in preaction or postaction.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain about the required output, but another way of faking rounded ends could be use the `line cap=round` key and getting the shading using repeated `\draw` commands with different line widths:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{shade}{final}{
  \state{final}{%
    \edef\currentlinewidth{\the\pgflinewidth}%
    \foreach \i in {100,98,...,0}
      \draw [line cap=round, line join=round, line width=\i/100*\currentlinewidth, 
        shade.outer.color!\i!shade.inner.color]
          \pgfextra{\pgfsetpath\pgfdecoratedpath};
  }
}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,
  inner color/.code=\colorlet{shade.inner.color}{#1},
  outer color/.code=\colorlet{shade.outer.color}{#1},
}
\tikzset{shade line/.style={
    decoration={shade, outer color=#1, inner color=white}, decorate
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=5pt]

\path [shade line=green] (0,0) -- (0,3);
\path [shade line=red]   (0,3) arc (90:0:3);
\path [shade line=blue]  (0,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here, the shading is symmetric.

Comment: Yes, and I wanted the shading to be not quite symmetric.  If the shading were symmetric, the existing code would work.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the desired output:

[image]

credits should go to Paul Gaborit for his [`cylindricalbar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354596/1952) and [`invclip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168/1952) codes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\def\cylindricalsphere{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{5pt}
    \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarspheres}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{\cylindricalsphere}
  \state{middle}[width=1pt]{}
  \state{final}{\cylindricalsphere}
}
\def\cylindricalsgement{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-.55pt}{-5pt}}{\pgfpoint{.55pt}{5pt}}
    \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarsegments}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{\cylindricalsgement}
  \state{middle}[width=1pt]{\cylindricalsgement}
  \state{final}{}
} 

\tikzset{
  cylindricalbar/.style={
    preaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarspheres},
    postaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarsegments},
  }
}

\tikzset{invclip/.style={clip,insert path={{[reset cm]
      (-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen) rectangle (\maxdimen,\maxdimen)
    }}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclareradialshading[mycolor,white]
  {barendshading}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{5bp}}
  {color(0bp)=(white);color(28bp)=(mycolor);color(60bp)=(mycolor)}

  \pgfdeclareverticalshading[mycolor,white]
  {barshading}{100bp}
  {color(0bp)=(mycolor);color(25bp)=(mycolor); 
    color(55bp)=(white);color(75bp)=(mycolor);color(100bp)=(mycolor)}


  \colorlet{mycolor}{green}
  \path [cylindricalbar]     (0,0) -- (0,3);

  \colorlet{mycolor}{red}
  \path [cylindricalbar]     (0,3) arc(90:0:3);

\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path[invclip] (-5pt,0) arc (-180:0:5pt)|-(-5pt,6pt);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \colorlet{mycolor}{blue}
  \path [cylindricalbar] (3,0) -- (0,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```